Can a basic reverse proxy be made with fastAPI like that?
Let's assume I have an environment where I cannot use existing solutions for reverse proxies like nginx, traefik and so on. On top, I can't use containerization. But I want to make a basic DIY reverse proxy with python and fastAPI. Nothing complex with load balancing or SSL termination or whatever. Just forwarding HTTP requests and websockets as transparently as possible. I want to make it resource efficient as in e.g. not having to hold the entire request/answer to forward in memory (e.g. when forwarding large file uploads/downloads).
I came up with some proof of concept implementation that already works for basic scenarios but especially when it comes to handling headers I'm afraid there is a lot that can go wrong? For now I take care of stripping the connection headers according to RFC 7230 but there's probably more to do? For websockets I don't even handle headers yet but maybe it's not necessary? The duplex communication with websockets seems to work though.
So, considering my circumstances, is this a valid approach or is this destined to fail? I'd be happy to read your suggestions. Any help is highly appreciated.
import contextlib

import anyio
import fastapi
import httpx
import starlette.background
import starlette.responses
import uvicorn
import websockets

client = httpx.AsyncClient()


@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: fastapi.FastAPI):
    yield
    await client.aclose()


service_mapping = {
    "x": "127.0.0.1:8001",
    "y": "127.0.0.1:8002",
}

app = fastapi.FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


def strip_connection_headers(headers: dict[str, str]) -> dict[str, str]:
    """RFC 7230 section 5.7 and 6.1"""
    lower_to_original_map = {k.strip().lower(): k for k in headers.keys()}
    result = headers.copy()

    if "connection" not in lower_to_original_map:
        return result

    connection_header_value = result[lower_to_original_map["connection"]]
    del result[lower_to_original_map["connection"]]

    for c in connection_header_value.split(","):
        c = lower_to_original_map.get(c.strip().lower())
        if c:
            del result[c]

    return result


@app.api_route(
    "/services/{service_name}/{path:path}",
    methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
)
async def forward_http_request(
    request_from_client: fastapi.Request,
    service_name: str,
    path: str,
):
    if service_name not in service_mapping:
        raise fastapi.HTTPException(
            status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"Service {service_name} not found",
        )

    base_url = f"http://{service_mapping[service_name]}"

    request_to_backend = client.build_request(
        method=request_from_client.method,
        url=f"{base_url}/{path}",
        headers=strip_connection_headers(dict(request_from_client.headers)),
        content=request_from_client.stream(),
        params=request_from_client.query_params,
    )

    response_from_backend = await client.send(request_to_backend, stream=True)

    return starlette.responses.StreamingResponse(
        content=response_from_backend.aiter_raw(),
        status_code=response_from_backend.status_code,
        headers=strip_connection_headers(dict(response_from_backend.headers)),
        background=starlette.background.BackgroundTask(
            response_from_backend.aclose
        ),
    )


@app.websocket("/ws/{service_name}/{path:path}")
async def forward_websocket_connection(
    websocket_with_client: fastapi.WebSocket,
    service_name: str,
    path: str,
):
    if service_name not in service_mapping:
        await websocket_with_client.close(
            code=fastapi.status.WS_1008_POLICY_VIOLATION,
            reason=f"service '{service_name}' unknown",
        )
        return

    await websocket_with_client.accept()

    base_url = f"ws://{service_mapping[service_name]}/{path}"

    websocket_with_backend = await websockets.connect(uri=base_url)

    async def forward_to_backend():
        while True:
            message = await websocket_with_client.receive()
            if message["type"] == "websocket.receive":
                message_content: str | bytes
                if "text" in message:
                    message_content = message["text"]
                else:
                    assert "bytes" in message
                    message_content = message["bytes"]
                await websocket_with_backend.send(message_content)
            else:
                assert message["type"] == "websocket.disconnect"
                task_group.cancel_scope.cancel()
                with anyio.CancelScope(shield=True):
                    await websocket_with_backend.close(
                        code=message["code"],
                        reason=message.get("reason", ""),
                    )
                    return

    async def forward_to_client():
        while True:
            try:
                message = await websocket_with_backend.recv()
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as e:
                task_group.cancel_scope.cancel()
                with anyio.CancelScope(shield=True):
                    await websocket_with_client.close(
                        code=e.code,
                        reason=e.reason,
                    )
                    return
            if isinstance(message, str):
                await websocket_with_client.send_text(message)
            else:
                assert isinstance(message, bytes)
                await websocket_with_client.send_bytes(message)

    async with anyio.create_task_group() as task_group:
        task_group.start_soon(forward_to_backend)
        task_group.start_soon(forward_to_client)


def main():
    uvicorn.run(
        "main:app",
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=8000,
        log_level="info",
        reload=True,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



Be careful! httpx accepts the username:password@ option in URLs. That might allow to construct URLs outside out what is defined in service_mapping by using a specially crafted path.

You will almost certainly want to add auto-computed Host headers, and you may want to add an accept: */*.   If the upstream services are on a VPS, many require host. Middleware like CDNs will utilize accept. You see tools like curl auto-adding these headers on all simple requests e.g. curl -v -X 'GET' 'http://<your-proxy>/services/<A>/script.js'
